# R - trying to create an ARIMA forecasting graph

Tags: r, time-series

So I'm trying to create a graph with an `ARIMA` forecast like this example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbIcY.png)

But I'm just not getting it right. I can't even get it to display a graph.
Here is my code:

```
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

#TEST DATA AND TEST CODE#
Pricing <- c(500,1000,2000,1500,3500,4000,2000,2500,500,3000,7500,5500,4000,5000,6000,500,3000,1500)
Time <- c("2010-01-01", "2010-07-02", "2010-08-03", "2011-02-04", "2011-11-05", "2011-12-06", "2012-06-07", "2012-08-30", "2013-04-16", "2013-03-18", "2014-02-22", "2014-01-27", "2015-12-15", "2015-09-28", "2016-05-04", "2017-11-07", "2017-09-22", "2017-04-04")
PriceFrame <- data.frame(Time,Pricing)
write.table(PriceFrame,file="C:/....path..../PriceFrame.txt",quote=F)

#THE FUNCTION#
Frame <- read.table("C:/....path..../PriceFrame.txt", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)
Frame$Time <- as.Date(Frame$Time, format= "%Y-%m-%d")
Frame <- ts(Frame$Pricing, start = 1, end=NROW(Frame), frequency=1)
TheForecast <- Arima(Frame, order = c(0,0,0))
write.table(TheForecast,file="C:/....path..../TheForecast.txt",quote=F)

#CODE TO PROVIDE AN EXAMPLE GRAPH AND EXAMPLE FORECAST DATA#
plot(TheForecast, xlab="Time",ylab="Price",main="Price vs Time",type='l')
print(TheForecast)
```

After I create the graph, I would like to save the forecast data a txt file as well (as my code shows), but the code doesn't like that I'm trying to convert an ARIMA to a data.frame.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: you have `frequency = 1`, what time interval are you looking at?

Comment: Monthly preferably, but I was just making a default so that any time can be shown for testing purposes. Would that affect the ARIMA?

Comment: Please read this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245791/what-is-the-frequency-in-my-series-and-does-it-matter-for-my-forecasting-models. I would suggest, before writing into file, work on forecasting and then you can add `write.table` argument

Comment: You also have it wrong by having `start=1` and `end=NROW(Frame)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have monthly frequency: try,

```
Frame <- ts(Frame$Pricing, start = c(2010, 01), end=c(2017, 04), frequency=12)
```

`forecast` and plot the graph.

Comment: The problem with that is that the data I'm using is just test data. I need the forecast to fit lists of varying price over time values, so the start and end values could change.

Comment: @Impact as mentioned in the answer you have to use `forecast` to forecast what ever the time lag you're looking at in the future. i.e. `youreforecast <- plot(forecast(TheForecast ,h=10))`

Comment: So I've changes the line with the plot to this: MyForecast <- plot(forecast(TheForecast,h=10)), and I got a this graph. Agg, how do i add pictures to a comment? XD

Comment: Basically it shows a graph with the forecast, but the data is messed. Its just repeating the same ups and downs a few times

Comment: it will because it is based on your data and how well you select your `p`, `d`, `q` in `ARIMA`. Now you have `order = c(0,0,0)`. You can try `auto.arima` to select you `p,d,q`. I think you have to Read more about ARIMA.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your help. I've gotten much closer now :)

Comment: There you go ;)